# How to add "how did you hear about us?" dropdown to the BUY BUTTON cart in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I was able to follow the instructions [on this site](https://scrowp.com/community/dawn-theme/ask-how-customers-heard-about-your-store-on-the-cart-page-shopify-tutorial/#post-738) to get a "How did you hear about us?" dropdown field to show up on the main cart page for a shopify store. However, I only use the Buy Buttons on my own-hosted website.  Any ideas how to get this new field to show up in the Buy Button-generated cart?

This is the code that makes the Buy Button appear on my site. Is there something that can be added to this under "Cart" to pull in the "How did you hear about us" question?

```
<div id='product-component-1701116833004'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
(function () {
  var scriptURL = 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/latest/buy-button-storefront.min.js';
  if (window.ShopifyBuy) {
    if (window.ShopifyBuy.UI) {
      ShopifyBuyInit();
    } else {
      loadScript();
    }
  } else {
    loadScript();
  }
  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = scriptURL;
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);
    script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;
  }
  function ShopifyBuyInit() {
    var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
      domain: 'XXXXX.myshopify.com',
      storefrontAccessToken: '555f8b0e8383840db2ffef9508a976e3',
    });
    ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function (ui) {
      ui.createComponent('product', {
        id: '8256061538602',
        node: document.getElementById('product-component-1701116833004'),
        moneyFormat: '%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',
        options: {
  "product": {
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "calc(25% - 20px)",
          "margin-left": "20px",
          "margin-bottom": "50px"
        }
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "button": "Add to cart"
    }
  },
  "productSet": {
    "styles": {
      "products": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "margin-left": "-20px"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "modalProduct": {
    "contents": {
      "img": false,
      "imgWithCarousel": true,
      "button": false,
      "buttonWithQuantity": true
    },
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "100%",
          "margin-left": "0px",
          "margin-bottom": "0px"
        }
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "button": "Add to cart"
    }
  },
  "option": {},
  "cart": {
    "text": {
      "total": "Subtotal",
      "button": "Checkout"
    },
    "contents": {
      "note": true
    }
  },
  "toggle": {}
},
      });
    });
  }
})();
/*]]>*/
</script>
```